# FontForge-Made OpenType Font Missing Glyphs in Some (But Not All) Programs

Tags: fonts, opentype, fontforge

I've made a family of fonts. They render correctly on all programs but Google Chrome and several Adobe products, which seems to completely ignore a handful of symbols including the lowercase m, instead replacing them with a square space, which is detrimental. (This bug has been reproduced on Photoshop, Illustrator, and After Effects, and presumably most if not all other Adobe products.)

The letters not displayed are: m Đ Ð Ņ Ũ Ū

You can see that the letters displayed as blanks are actually existing letters that load on other programs. I made the font on FontForge, and it isn't returning any noticeable errors. Why is this happening, and how can I fix this problem?

This bug does not happen on Notepad, LibreOffice, GIMP, or Inkscape.

Two weights of the font (which I named Apricity, by the way) are available for download for free, and it has the same bug. [Here is the download link.](http://www.dafont.com/apricity.font)

Comment: not much point in calling something a bug unless you already know it's a bug. How does your font build those glyphs? Are they individual glyphs tied to Latin Extended codepoints, or does it only point to them through GPOS/GSUB features where Đ requires the user to type "D-" or "-D"?

Comment: I can reproduce the bug, indeed. I am also getting very high kerning values on certain pairs. Are you sure you are defining your classes correctly? I can't remember exactly where, but I read that if you have duplicated glyphs on certain classes, the kerning values adds.